# Recovering an old Perforce depot

Tags: perforce, recovery

I recently lost a lot of files, due to a hard disk error, but still have a Perforce folder containing files from a particular project. Trouble is, it's not the actual project files, but some kind of Perforce storage format, with files ending in ",d" and ",v"

Is there any way I can restore the original files from what I have?

I imagined Perforce would be able to open the folder as a depot, and I'd simply be able to get the files into a new workspace, but I can't see any way to open an existing depot. I tried editing the depot's "Storage location for versioned files" to point at the folder, but the depot still shows as empty.

I only used Perforce briefly (comparing it to Git) so I don't really understand how it works. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question might be answered on https://superuser.com/, StackOverflow is about coding and therefore for this question the wrong place.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're missing is the database (the `db.*` files), which need to be in the server root (`P4ROOT`) when you start the server.  If you don't have database files in `P4ROOT`, the server will create an empty database on startup.  The database is the source of truth for a Perforce server, so if it's empty, the server is empty.

If you have a checkpoint (a file called `checkpoint.N`) and/or `journal` file, that contains the metadata you need to reconstruct the database; recover the server with `p4d -jr checkpoint.N journal`, and then you can use the `p4 depot` command to make sure the `Map` of your depot(s) points at the directory where your archive files are, and use other commands to inspect the actual files (start with `p4 verify` to see which files are in the database but missing/corrupted in the archive backup).

If you *only* have the archive files but no database (and no checkpoint or journal to recover it from), you're in a more difficult spot since the database is what maps the archive files into the actual depot structure (e.g. it includes all the copy-by-reference pointers that constitute branches in Perforce).  However, you can extract the contents of the archive files one file at a time using conventional tools; the `,v` files are in RCS format (use the `co` command to retrieve their content), and the `,d` directories contain regular old `.gz` files, one per revision.

Using the [deep magic](https://perforce-user.perforce.narkive.com/RL95zzgL/p4-rcstoperforce-sh) to synthesize a database from the archive files on their own is also a possibility, but the RCS/CVS conversion scripts are so old I'd expect a lot of fiddling to be required to get them working with a current version of Perforce.